# Css for ToolTip does not work

Tags: html, css

I have seen [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip) link from W3school and i am trying to make it in my code.
and the css is in seperate fill:

```css
.tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    }
    
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 0;
    
        /* Position the tooltip */
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="purpose" class="col-sm-2 control-label text-right" >Purpose</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control tooltip"   placeholder="Purpose"
          th:field="*   {purpose}" th:required="required" id="Purpose"/>
                        
         <span class="tooltiptext">Article, Essay, Thesis, etc.</span>
        </div> 
      </div>
```

The problem is when i apply the `tooltip` the input element get hidden, but surprisingly it does not happen for `span` element.

So, why it makes my input invisible and there is no **tooltip**?

Comment: Your input has the class 'tooltip', but the span is not inside the input, so '.tooltip .tooltiptext' isn't going to work. I think that class needs to be on the parent. If you copy code from somewhere, make sure to add a link, so your SO buddies can have a look and check if you missed something, instead of people just making wild guesses which will poor in in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: Your css assumes the `tooltiptext` is insight the `tooltip` but that is not the case in your html.

Comment: `.tooltip, .tooltiptext` seperate with `,`

Comment: Add container div for 'tooltiptext'... eg: 
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
 <span class="tooltiptext">Article, Essay, Thesis, etc.</span>
</div>

Comment: Your addition confirms my previous statement. In the W3Schools example, the tooltip class is on the div that is the parent of the span. Put a div there, with `class='tooltip' and put the span and the input in there.

Answer (score 3):

**DEMO:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/f88jEBhGIfVtm0eLa9Cf?p=preview

It is because your html and CSS rules does not match.

You have added `tooltip` class to input and written `tooltiptext` next to it (as a sibling). But as per your CSS, the `tooltiptext` should be inside `tooltip`. So, in my demo I added a wrapper with class `tooltip` that will wrap the input and the span with class `tooltiptext`. You can edit it further as per your needs.

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="purpose" class="col-sm-2 control-label text-right" >Purpose</label>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="tooltip">
     <input type="text" class="form-control"   placeholder="Purpose"
      th:field="*   {purpose}" th:required="required" id="Purpose"/>

     <span class="tooltiptext">Article, Essay, Thesis, etc.</span>
  </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.tooltiptext` is next class of the hover element.so use with `+` in hover comment of css

```css
.tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    }
    
   .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 0;
    
        /* Position the tooltip */
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .tooltip:hover + .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="purpose" class="col-sm-2 control-label text-right" >Purpose</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input type="text" class="tooltip"   placeholder="Purpose"
          th:field="*   {purpose}" th:required="required" id="Purpose"/>
                        
         <span class="tooltiptext">Article, Essay, Thesis, etc.</span>
        </div> 
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.tooltip` is a void element meaning it has no end tag, therefore it can never have any children.

```
.tooltip  .tooltiptext
```

This means get the element with the class `.tooltiptext` which is a **descendant** of `.tooltip`. As I mentioned earlier, `.tooltip` is incapable of having children.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control tooltip" id="Purpose" />

    <span class="tooltiptext">Article, Essay, Thesis, etc.</span>
```

After cleaning up the clutter, one can plainly so that `.tooltip` is actually a ***sibling*** of `.tooltiptext`. Better yet, `.tooltiptext` is an ***adjacent sibling*** of `.tooltip`.

A `+` means to get the sibling next immediate sibling of `.tooltip`

```
.tooltip:hover + .tooltiptext 
.tooltip + .tooltip
```

## or

A `~` means to get a sibling that follows `.tooltip`, so it's a little less    specific because it's able to target a sibling with class `.tooltiptext` further down the line if necessary.

```
 .tooltip:hover ~ .tooltiptext 
 .tooltip ~ .tooltiptext
```

See this article about [sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

I also added the Bootstrap files, but it'll work without them as well.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.tooltip + .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tooltip:hover + .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="purpose" class="col-sm-2 control-label text-right">Purpose</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control tooltip" placeholder="Purpose" th:field="*   {purpose}" th:required="required" id="Purpose" />

    <span class="tooltiptext">Article, Essay, Thesis, etc.</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```